# What do the dashed lines represent in this image from the View Controller Programming Guide?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

I'm reading from Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheViewControllerHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH33-SW1) and I'm attempting to understand the idea of what the root view controller object is.  The diagram below somewhat makes sense so the part that doesn't is trying to figure out what the dashed lines represent.

Allow me to talk through what I assume to understand as correct and if its not please let me know:

The UIWindow Object is a property of the AppDelegate file.  The rootViewController is set by going to the menu in Xcode and selecting "Embed in..." which is most likely a navigation controller.  The first view controller object is then set as the initial view controller within the navigation controller (rootViewController).  This view controller then has a view property which can receive additional subviews such as uitextfield, uibutton, etc.

I'm just not sure why this diagram has dashed lines going back around to the UIWindow but would like an explanation if anyone can help or am I reading too deep into it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the next diagram in the document you link. that double-bordered green rectangle that the dash lines connect to appears to be the iOS device/screen.